# SQL Server : stored procedure insert fails without any errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm a newbie to SQL Server stored procedures. I have a problem with a stored procedure that runs some queries and an "insert" as the last one. This insert works good outside the procedure fine, but not when I call the procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[create_pre_register_demand]
        @login = N'asd',
        @password_hash = N'asd',
        @type = N'asd',
        @egrpo = N'asd',
        @rnokpp = N'asd',
        @passport = N'asd',
        @short_client_descr = N'asd',
        @full_client_descr = N'asd',
        @legal_address = N'asd',
        @physical_address = N'asd',
        @bank_name = N'asd',
        @bank_iban = N'asd',
        @mfo = N'asd',
        @main_contact_surname = N'asd',
        @main_contact_name = N'asd',
        @main_contact_lastname = N'asd',
        @phone = N'asd',
        @email = N'asd'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

I get back: Return value - 0.

But I cannot see any new records in my table. If I execute the insert outside of procedure, it works ok and I can see one new record in the table.

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[create_pre_register_demand]
    @login varchar(max),
    @password_hash varchar(max),
    @type varchar(1),
    @egrpo varchar(8),
    @rnokpp varchar(12),
    @passport varchar(8),
    @short_client_descr varchar(32),
    @full_client_descr varchar(64),
    @legal_address varchar(64),
    @physical_address varchar(64),
    @bank_name varchar(32),
    @bank_iban varchar(32),
    @mfo varchar(10),
    @main_contact_surname varchar(32),
    @main_contact_name varchar(32),
    @main_contact_lastname varchar(32),
    @phone varchar(32),
    @email varchar(32) AS
BEGIN
    --check by egrpo
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT [b_member_id] FROM [dbo].[at_b_client] WHERE [number_edrpou] LIKE @egrpo)
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Egrpo is already taken'
                RETURN
            END
    END

    --check by rnokpp
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT [b_member_id] FROM [dbo].[at_b_client] WHERE [number_edrpou] LIKE @rnokpp)
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Rnokpp is already taken'
                RETURN
            END
    END
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT [b_member_id] FROM [dbo].[at_b_client] WHERE [number_rnokpp] LIKE @rnokpp)
            PRINT 'Rnokpp is already taken'
            RETURN
    END

    --check by passport
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT [b_member_id] FROM [dbo].[at_b_client] WHERE [passport] LIKE @passport)
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Rassport number or serial is already exists'
                RETURN
            END
    END

    --check email contains @
    -- it must be a simple email validator in serviceapi
    -- BEGIN
    -- END

    --generate memberId
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @memberIdLength INT
        DECLARE @MaxMemberId VARCHAR(max)
        DECLARE @zeroesQuantityToBeAdded VARCHAR(max)
        DECLARE @count INT = 0
        DECLARE @NewMemberId varchar(9)

        SELECT @memberIdLength = len(MAX([b_member_id])) FROM [dbo].[at_b_client]
        SELECT @MaxMemberId = MAX([b_member_id]) FROM [dbo].[at_b_client]
        SELECT @MaxMemberId = SUBSTRING(@MaxMemberId, 3, @memberIdLength)
        SELECT @MaxMemberId = @MaxMemberId+1
        SELECT @zeroesQuantityToBeAdded = @memberIdLength - len(@MaxMemberId+1);
        SELECT @zeroesQuantityToBeAdded = @zeroesQuantityToBeAdded - 2 --Minus two because of we have prefix B_
        SELECT @zeroesQuantityToBeAdded = CONVERT(varchar(9), @zeroesQuantityToBeAdded)
        SELECT @NewMemberId = @MaxMemberId

        WHILE @count < @zeroesQuantityToBeAdded
        BEGIN
            SELECT @NewMemberId = CONCAT('0', @NewMemberId)
            SET @count = @count + 1
        END

        SELECT @NewMemberId = CONCAT('B_', @NewMemberId)
        PRINT @NewMemberId;
    END

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[at_b_client]
               ([b_member_id]
               ,[b_client_type_id]
               ,[status]
               ,[short_name]
               ,[full_name]
               ,[legal_address]
               ,[fact_address]
               ,[last_contact_name]
               ,[first_contact_name]
               ,[middle_contact_name]
               ,[phone]
               ,[email]
               ,[note]
               ,[number_edrpou]
               ,[number_rnokpp]
               ,[passport]
               ,[iban]
               ,[bank_code]
               ,[bank_name]
               ,[b_client_login]
               ,[b_client_password]
               ,[b_client_api_key_pms]
               ,[date_add]
               ,[date_status_create]
               ,[date_status_cancel]
               ,[is_deleted])
        VALUES
               (@NewMemberId,
               @type
               ,0
               ,@short_client_descr
               ,@full_client_descr
               ,@legal_address
               ,@full_client_descr
               ,@main_contact_surname
               ,@main_contact_name
               ,@main_contact_lastname
               ,@phone
               ,@email
               ,'' --note
               ,@egrpo
               ,@rnokpp
               ,@passport
               ,@bank_iban
               ,''--should be bank code
               ,@bank_name
               ,@login
               ,@password_hash
               ,''--b_client_api-keypms
               ,''
               ,''
               ,''
               ,0)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH  
        SELECT   
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
           ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: `0` means success for the `RETURN` value, not failure. Anything *other* than `0` means failure. Also, why are you `SELECT`ing the values of the `ERROR` and not `THROW`ing the error?

Comment: Also, instead of that `WHILE`, why not use `REPLICATE()` to add leading values to a string type value?

Comment: I dont touch this part of code because it works. But my insert replies me return value - 0 but not inserting any records in table - this is the problem.

Comment: You eat the error in your catch - that is not proper error handling. And there is room for extensive improvement here. You should NOT be using PRINT to return information to an application - throw errors that your app can catch and handle as desired.

Comment: Change your catch block to only `THROW;`.

Comment: BEGIN CATCH  
  PRINT 'Some error occured';  
  THROW;
    END CATCH

Comment: Still no changes

Comment: Maybe some synthax errors ? I have changed catch block to throw only, but still no changes. Return value - 0

Comment: Are you executing this via management studio?  If so do you get a `Messages` tab by the results window and does it show anything?

Comment: Yes, via management studio. Messages tab says - Commands completed successfully.

Completion time: 2020-11-19T16:27:20.9163060+02:00

Comment: https://ibb.co/DMsBxt9

Comment: https://ibb.co/Lg4JNJQ

Comment: This statement `IF EXISTS(SELECT [b_member_id] FROM [dbo].[at_b_client] WHERE [number_rnokpp] LIKE @rnokpp)` is missing BEGIN and END so that means only the following line is part of that.   So RETURN is getting executed every time the stored procedure is executed and terminating your procedure.   Wrap the 2 lines after, like your others, in BEGIN/END and try it again.

Comment: the `--check by rnokpp` section, appears you have the IF EXIST twice, the second is missing BEGIN/END

Comment: Thanks Tim Mylott it helped! Now i can see another errors!